# Exporting Excel file with Filters Present to a CSV File

Tags: excel, csv, filter, export-to-csv

How can you export an excel file to a .CSV file with all of the filters present on the .xlsx file applied?

I have ~1000 rows of data in an .xlsx file, but only require rows with certain criteria to be exported to the .csv file. When exporting with the filters on the row, obviously all of the data is just exported to the .csv file, not just the visible data present after the filter. I require just the filtered data, as the report is handling live data which changes, and my program can only import .csv files due to internal policies.

Sorry this isn't quite a programming question; however the answer will be used to implement this into a programmed solution, which I am hoping to provide on this thread after it has been completed.

Comment: How about copying the filtered data and pasting to a new workbook, then saving that workbook as a CSV?

Comment: This isn't really a suitable solution, as the data set is being live updated, and therefore each time I'd have to copy and paste the data and make an new file. Whereas I can program something which would export a .csv each time the program is opened to get the most up to date .xlsx filtered data :)

Comment: You can program something to refresh the data, do the copy-and-paste and save as a CSV each time the file is opened. The result is the same.

Comment: Wouldn't you still have to manually copy and paste the data each time in order for the refresh to show the new live data?

I want a fully automated conversion, not requiring any manual copy and paste. Thanks again!

Comment: (Almost) anything you can do manually, you can do programmatically: #ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select #Range(Selection, Cells(1)).Select #Selection.Copy #Workbooks.Add #ActiveSheet.Paste